# Show images in a View based on a specific JSON field

Tags: json, image, swiftui, field

I have an app that has to show several images (in a LazyVGrid), and I want to check if a specific word is present in a specific field of a JSON file that the app loads at start. It is possible?

Waiting for help, thank you!

Here's the code for the View:

```
import SwiftUI
import URLImage

struct GalleryView: View {
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
    ]
    
    @ObservedObject var dm: DownloadManager
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(dm.JSON) { busso in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ImageView(busso: busso)) {
                        VStack(alignment: .center) {
                            URLImage(URL(string: busso.fotoUrl) ?? furl)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            Text(busso.titolo)
                                .font(.headline)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 8.0)
        .navigationBarTitle("Galleria", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct GalleryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GalleryView(dm: DownloadManager())
    }
}
```

Here's the code of the JSON file (I want the app to check for the word "image" in the "extra1" field, if possible)

```
[
    {
        "id": "3",
        "titolo": "Panorama",
        "autore": "Descrizione",
        "testo": "",
        "data": "",
        "extra1": "image",
        "extra2": "",
        "creazione": "2021-01-07 11:21:53",
        "foto": "foto\/WP_20161110_001.jpg",
        "fotoUrl": "http:\/\/geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org\/foto\/WP_20161110_001.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "titolo": "Comune di Busso",
        "autore": "Contatti",
        "testo": "Indirizzo, telefono, mail, altri dati da inserire",
        "data": "",
        "extra1": "",
        "extra2": "",
        "creazione": "2021-01-01 19:33:56",
        "foto": "foto\/DSCN0914.JPG",
        "fotoUrl": "http:\/\/geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org\/foto\/DSCN0914.JPG"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "titolo": "Chiesa",
        "autore": "Luoghi da visitare",
        "testo": "Testo di prova, abbastanza lungo per verificare l'impaginazione e correggere eventuali errori.",
        "data": "",
        "extra1": "",
        "extra2": "",
        "creazione": "2021-01-01 19:32:02",
        "foto": "foto\/CAM_0044.JPG",
        "fotoUrl": "http:\/\/geniuspointfrezza.altervista.org\/foto\/CAM_0044.JPG"
    }
]
```

Comment: You can filter your array data and then load data into the view.

Comment: @RajaKishan Could you please make an example of code? It’s my first app, so I’m still learning...thank you!

Comment: @RajaKishan I had to work on the code a bit, but in the end - thanks to your tip - I managed to get the result I wanted...thank you so much!

Comment: You welcome :).